# Getting P-value While Using Variance

Tags: statistics

**Suppose we observe a random sample of five measurements: 10, 13, 15, 15, 17, from a normal distribution with unknown mean $\mu_1$ and unknown variance $\sigma_1^2$, A second random sample from another normal population with unknown mean $\mu_2$ and unknown variance $\sigma_2^2$ yields the measurements: 13, 7, 9, 11.**

**a) Test for evidence that $\sigma_1 > 1.0$. Complete the P-value for this test as accurately as possible. Draw a conclusion at $\alpha = 0.05$.**

Here's what I've done so far:

Step#1: Calculate $\sigma_1$

$\sigma_1 = \sqrt \frac{(10-14)^2 + (13-14)^2 + (15-14)^2 + (15-14)^2 + (17-14)^2}{5} = \sqrt\frac{28}{5} = 2.366$

Step#2: Set up Hypothesis Test

$H_0: \sigma_1 = 2.366$

$H_a: \sigma_1 > 1.0$

How do I proceed from here? Thanks.

EDIT:

Also have this question, and would appreciate some insight.

**b) Use the pivotal method(and a pivotal statistic with F distribution) to derive a 95% confidence interval for $\frac{\sigma_2}{\sigma_1}$. Work it out for these data. And test the null hypothesis that $\sigma_2 = \sigma_1$ at the 5% level of significance.**

Comment: Incidentally, there's a statistics site in the stackexchange group. If you don't get what you need here, you could try over there (but be sure to link each question to the other to prevent duplication of effort).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for part a), you've made a wrong null hypothesis test.  You want to test for evidence that $\sigma_1\gt{1}\to\sigma_1^2\gt{1}$.  Thus, your hypotheses should be:
$$H_0:\sigma_1^2=1$$
$$H_1:\sigma_1^2\gt1$$
We need $n_1$ which is 5.  We also need our sample variance, which you have the square root of. Thus, $S^2=5.6$ and now we calculate our chi-square statistic, which is 
$$\chi^2=\frac{(n-1)s^2}{\sigma_0^2}=\frac{(5-1)(5.6)}{1}=22.4$$
We know our $\alpha=.05$, so we need to find $\chi_{\alpha}^2(n-1)=\chi_{.05}^2(4)=9.488.$
Since $22.4\ge9.488$, we reject $H_0.$
By p-value, we can see that at $\alpha=.01, P(W\ge{13.28})=.01$, so our p-value is less than .01. Also, $P(W\ge{14.86})=.005$, so it would appear that our p-value for this problem is VERY small indeed!

for part b), we know that $s_1^2=5.6$ and $s_2^2=\frac{(13-10)^2+(7-10)^2+(9-10)^2+(11-10)^2}{4}=5.$.  ALso, let m be the number of measurements from the first random sample and let n be the number of measurements from the second random sample.  Considering the scope of deriving the confidence, I give it to you freely here:
$$.95CI\left(\frac{\sigma_2^2}{\sigma_1^2}\right)=\left[\frac{1}{F_{\frac{\alpha}{2}}(n-1)(m-1)}\frac{s_2^2}{s_1^2},F_{\frac{\alpha}{2}}(m-1)(n-1)\frac{s_2^2}{s_1^2}\right]=\left[\frac{1}{F_{.025}(4)(3)}\frac{5.6}{5},F_{.025}(3)(4)\frac{5.6}{5}\right]$$
Since I gave you the freebee, you should try and finish the hypothesis test for the ratio using what you know of the F-statistic and the information provided...

Comment: It's going to take me a while to digest, but thanks, I think I got it now.

Comment: no problem.  The F stuff is not easy to understand, but I would try and push through it because if you understand it, you should understand most of CI's and hypothesis testing.